# AWS EC2 Unreachable instance after Resize

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2016

I have 2 r3.xlarge AWS EC2 instances that are convertible to r4.xlarge. They are both running Exchange 2016 on 2012R2.  I have tried two methods so far:

1. Changed instance type and booted up
2. Created AMI and Launched a new instance with it

In both cases, the servers became unreachable and passed only 1\2 checks.
I've attached the Elastic IP to both with no results.

Am I missing something here?  Does something need to happen to these instances specifically because they're running Exchange?

Comment: what does access/event logs say when retrieved from web console?

Comment: You mentioned that they are r3.xlarge.  Was that before or after?  What was the other instance type?

Comment: I have fixed the instance types.

Comment: Shailesh, what logs are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

In order to upgrade from r3.xlarge to r4.xlarge, you will have to install the new ENA and PV drivers from Amazon.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html